# Android Studio crashes on run after successful build

Tags: android, android-studio

(Android newbie here.)

I am running Android Studio on Mac OS 10.7. I am trying to run a basic "Hello world" app but it crashes on run after building (BUILD SUCCESSFUL).

I am new to both Android and Android Studio and don't know what to do to figure out the source of the error or how to fix it.

TIA!